# rails s says "brunch_watcher.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)" in RailsInstaller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed [breakfast](http://breakfast.devlocker.io) in my rails project on Windows 10 PC. When I run `rails s` and it throw exception

```
D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/breakfast-0.5.1/lib/breakfast/brunch_watcher.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- pty (LoadError)
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/breakfast-0.5.1/lib/breakfast/brunch_watcher.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/breakfast-0.5.1/lib/breakfast.rb:3:in `require'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/breakfast-0.5.1/lib/breakfast.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
    from D:/ProjectExt/confess_server/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from D:/Development/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
```

Comment: Have you included that breakfast gem in your gemfile? If so, do bundle install once and try again

Comment: I had included breakfast gem, but run `rails s` throws exception